# Restricted access page not visible in IE( 8 and 7) problem with cookieDomain variable in typo3

Tags: typo3

FE Restricted access page works fine with Firefox, but in IE and chrome it not. Cookie domain is not set properly on IE. I come across with some patch , it not seems to be work.

My current localconf.php configuration is:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['cookieDomain'] = 'www.domain.com';
```

i tried domain.com also.

i come across many bugs reported regarding this issue. http://bugs.typo3.org/view.php?id=11858

In google chrome also i am facing the same problem.

Non of the solution works for me.

What should be the configuration for cookie domain.

> Typo3 Version: 4.4.9   PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny13

Comment: I you are asking questions you should not abandon them. People are working for you so at least respond to their efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Your cookieDomain config is correct. A more stable and versatile version would look like this:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['cookieDomain'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

This one also works in multi-website / multi-domain setups.

If you still experience problems, you should check the Set-Cookie header that is sent in the server response: Use FF with Add-on "Live HTTP headers" (LHh). First delete any existing cookies for your domain (Firefox: Tools –> Options –> Privacy –> remove individual cookies –> select all entries matching your domain –> hit "remove cookies"), now open the LHh window (tools menu, last entry), keep it open and open your website in FF. Then inspect the response that comes back from the server after the first GET request. It should start with

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

and should contain a line like this

```
Set-Cookie: fe_typo_user=abcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh; path=/; domain=www.domain.com
```

Check whether the domain is the one that you are calling the website by and the path is root ("/").

If this is all correct, your login problem is probably not connected to the cookieDomain setting.